# How pass information between forms involving listView item being changed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have file manager program that displays folder in a treeView on the left hand side of a form (frmMain)  and files in listView on the left side. I want to be able to select a file (item) from the listView then display the file name in a text on another form with the label = 'Enter a file name.' then rename the file with that new name.

Code from the second form.

```
public frmRename(string oFile)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        textBox1.Text = oFile;
    }

private void bntOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nFileName;
    nFileName = textBox1.Text;
    frmMain fm = new frmMain();
    fm.re_nameFile(nFileName);
}
```

This code runs without any errors; however, when uncommented that is presently commented I get error 'Value of zero is not a valid for index'. I know that this error has talked about a lot; however, I am concern with a different aspect of this error. If I use a line of in private function I don't get this error; whereas, if I use it public function I do. First of all I want to understand why this happens? Second can you tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in frmMain you create a new frmRename and in frmRename you create a new frmMain. Bad idea. The new frmMain knows nothing about the original frmMain (including its populated listView).

Solution: in frmMain.bntRename_Click call

```
rename.ShowDialog();
newFileName = rename.nFileName;
```

do whatever you want to do with the new name and in frmRename define

```
public string nFileName {get; private set;}
```

and further change

```
private void bntOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nFileName = textBox1.Text;
    Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works! Just one question: Why are using a private here rather than just set?

Comment: The rule in object oriented programming is to make everything private that does not need to be public. I guess that is what is called a lean interface in English, meaning that you are going to have less responsibility and less work with it in the future. Your new filename can be readonly for the outside world. After all it is not so much important in your simple case.